# Why does Azure Synapse limit the Storage Node size to 60?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I see that Synapse provisioned SQL pool (SQL DW) design keeps the data distribution limited to 60 nodes. Am I understanding that limitation correctly?

If so, how and why did Microsoft arrive with this specific number? Why 60 and not (say) 50 or 70? I am asking for an explanation of the design decision that led to the product having a configuration limit.

Answer (score 1):

It was a number that had many factors :)

60 is the number of SQL distributions, which are supported on 1 to 60 nodes.

We can use 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30 or 60 (did I get all of them?) possible nodes per scale configuration.

Comment: Yes, but the question still remains - why is the maximum number set as 60?  Why not 50? How did they come to a decision that 60 is the optimum number for data distribution.

Comment: @Vibha because 50 would only support 4 configurations, not 12, as it is only divisible by 10, 5, 2 and 1. We evenly distribute the number of distributions across the nodes, so we need whole number divisors. Why not 120, you may ask? Because then we'd have issues putting all the distributions on a single node.